# Index on the embedded documents as whole

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure on the document

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("1234"),
  "name": "TestName",
  "location": { state: "NY", city: "New York" ,"geoid":28042},
  "ts":<timestamp>
..
..
}..
```

I have around 1 GB of data on with the above collection.

I have created an index on the location i.e `db.mydata.createIndex( { location: 1 } )`. I have three following questions.

1. What will be the impact on the performance if I create an index on the whole document?
2. Since the index is on `"location"`, if I use `"location.state"="NY"`, does this query use the above-defined index?
3. Does index is used when my query is `"location.city"="New York"` and `"location.state"="NY"`? Does order matters here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an index on the subdocument `location` it will have same impact as creating any other index as it will need to do a full collection scan and build up the index.

With an index on `location`, you won't be able to do a query of `location.state` as this does not match the whole sub-document. You'll only be use the index if you do the following query to match the sub document:

```js
db.test.find({ "location": { state: "NY", city: "New York" ,"geoid":28042} }
```

This is because the index is on the field `location` not on `location.state`, if you needed to match on `state` and `city` I'd suggest that you add an index on both them fields.

```js
db.test.createIndex({"location.state" : 1, "location.city": 1});
```

That way your query could use the index for `state` and for `state and`city`.

if we put this together in a simple example we can all run, we can look at the execution plan.

if let's insert a document with a sub-document.

```js
db.test.insertOne({
  subDocument: { field1 : 1, field2 : 2 }
});
```

Now we can create an index on `subDocument`:

```js
db.test.createIndex({subDocument:1})
```

Then we run a explain on the query for `field1` only.

```js
db.test.find( { "subDocument.field1" : 1 } ).explain()
```

```js
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.test",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "subDocument.field1" : {
                                "$eq" : 1
                        }
                },
                "queryHash" : "CEC76D6B",
                "planCacheKey" : "CEC76D6B",
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "subDocument.field1" : {
                                        "$eq" : 1
                                }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : { },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

as you can see the winning plan is `COLLSCAN`.

Now let's query based on the whole document instead.

```js
db.test.find({"subDocument": {field1: 1, field2: 2 }}).explain()
```

```js
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.test",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "subDocument" : {
                                "$eq" : {
                                        "field1" : 1,
                                        "field2" : 2
                                }
                        }
                },
                "queryHash" : "3B0F9692",
                "planCacheKey" : "7CF9BAC4",
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "subDocument" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "subDocument_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "subDocument" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "subDocument" : [
                                                "[{ field1: 1.0, field2: 2.0 }, { field1: 1.0, field2: 2.0 }]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : { },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now we can see it using the index scan `IXSCAN`.

Comment: Thanks this is very usefull